# How to choose exact size of rectangle on Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

I am trying to find out how to resize a rectangle without having to adjust it manually

Comment: Typing in your measurements does not work? There ought to be a screen wide cntrol bar at the top of your window where you can do so.

Comment: Hi Lazoro, welcome to GDSE. It seems your question attracted a few downvotes, because our community thinks it's too easy to find the answer through a simple web search. Please see the [help] to find out more about which questions we think fit our site. Keep contributing and thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the dimensions of the rectangle, you can select the Rectangle Tool and click the canvas once. This will bring up a window that you can input any width and height you desire:

[image]

[image]

If you decide to edit the dimensions after you've created the rectangle, you can adjust the width and height in the tool bar across the top of the workspace that appears when the shape tool is selected.